# How to sort data from a csv by a unique Key identifier in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following data in a csv:

```
KEY,VARNAME1,VARNAME2,VARNAME3  
**1**,10,20,30  
**1**,9,18,25  
**1**,8,10,0  
**2**,40,80,90  
**2**,35,70,80  
**2**,5,0,0
```

I want to read the data from this csv and write a new CSV that looks like this:

```
**1**,**2**  
10,40  
9,35  
8,5  
20,80  
18,70  
10,0  
30,90  
25,80  
0,0
```

In other words: The "KEY" for each row is the new header in the new csv. The values for the variables VARNAME1, VARNAME2 etc. are put together in one column for each "KEY".

The data is very very big. It is up to 50 GB (one file). That's why I am not writing a Macro or anything else I am used.

I am struggling a little bit with the sytax of powershell.

I am reading the csv without problems. But then I am not sure how to write the right FOR-Loop.

Or do I need to set up a Hash-Table, also having in mind the huge amount of data?

Comment: How many "keys" are we talking about per file? The "easy" way of re-modeling the data to the output format you want would require having it all in memory at once, but that might not be desirable given the file size

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: The number of keys can also be very large ~ 1 Mio. I agree that the main problem is the amoint of data that need be stored in the memory. I hoped that there is an effective way of doing this without loading everything in to the memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

I almost hesitate to post this because it *definitely* won't scale to a 50gb file, but it gives you a basic algorithm for looping through your data to get the desired output that you can use as a starting point...

```
$csv = @"
KEY,VARNAME1,VARNAME2,VARNAME3
1,10,20,30
1,9,18,25
1,8,10,0
2,40,80,90
2,35,70,80
2,5,0,0
"@

$data = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv;

# get the property names from the data
# i.e. VARNAME1, VARNAME2, VARNAME3
$propertyNames = $data[0].psobject.Properties.Name | where-object { $_ -ne "KEY" }

# group by key so we can pair up the Nth row from each key group together.
# note - this won't scale very well :-(
$groups = $data | group-object "KEY"

# basically, transpose the data so that the VARNAME1 values from the
# first "KEY=1" record and the first "KEY=2" record are paired together,
# then the VARNAME1 values from the second "KEY=1" record and the second
# "KEY=2", etc, until we've processed all the records for VARNAME1, then
# start again with the VARNAME2 property, then VARNAME3. assumes there's 
# the same number of "KEY=1" and "KEY=2" records
$rows = @()
foreach( $propertyName in $propertyNames )
{
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $groups[0].Count; $i++ )
    {
        $row = [ordered] @{};
        foreach( $group in $groups )
        {
            $row.Add($group.Name, $group.Group[$i].$propertyName)
        }
        # += is exponentially expensive for very big dataset
        $rows += new-object PSCustomObject -Property $row
    }
}

$csv = $rows | ConvertTo-Csv

# note - strings instead of ints
$csv
# "1","2"
# "10","40"
# "9","35"
# "8","5"
# "20","80"
# "18","70"
# "10","0"
# "30","90"
# "25","80"
# "0","0"
```